# gb4e: Pull out only subexample label

Tags: cross-referencing, linguistics, gb4e

Is there a way to pull out just the subexample number for a reference when using gb4e? Sometimes I'd like to do something like "In the (a) example(s)...," without having the number. It feels like this should be possible, but I can't seem to find how anywhere.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
Blah blah blah...

Here are some examples...
\begin{exe}
    \ex \begin{xlist}
        \ex[]{This is an example.}\label{sub1}
        \ex[*]{This example an is.}\label{sub2}
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

As with the previous cases, we see here that the \ref{sub1} example is grammatical, while the \ref{sub2} example is not.

\end{document}
```

The goal would be to replace `\ref{sub1}` and `\ref{sub2}` with commands that will just pull out the (a) and (b) parts, without including the preceding number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `refcount` and `xstring` packages:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\subref}[1]{\StrRight{\getrefnumber{#1}}{1}}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{top}
\begin{xlist}
\ex Example \label{sub}
\ex Example \label{sub2}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

In the (\subref{sub2}) examples. In the (\subref{sub}) examples.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]